# ReferenceMany generates a $pushAll field, which throw an error when trying to save a MongoGridFs file

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-odm

Ok guys, either I'm missing something big, or I just walked on a bug.

That's a Sf2 (v2.0.9) / Doctrine ODM (1.0.0BETA) project.

Basically, I've two documents, let's call them E and P:

- E references many P:

  ```
     /**
      * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="P", simple="true")
      * @MongoDB\Index
      */
      protected $p = array();
  ```
- I don't care to be able to retrieve corresponding E's from P.

I've generated E's getter/setter with `doctrine:mongodb:generate:documents`.

When I declare a new E() then add some existing P's ($e->addP($p)), like that:

```
$p1 = $this->dm->getRepository('ProjectBundle:P')->findOneBy(array('id' => $pid1)));
$p2 = $this->dm->getRepository('ProjectBundle:P')->findOneBy(array('id' => $pid2)));
$pArr = array($p1, $p2);
$e = new E();
foreach ($pArr as $p) {
  $e->addP();
}
```

(Don't look too deep at that piece of code, please, it's less crappy in my controller but I'm still basically doing a `foreach($pArr as $p)` on `$e->addP($p)`).

I end up with that kind of object in my collection E:

```
"$pushAll": {
   "p": [
    "0": ObjectId("4f4ba859c883fdf85e00313a"),
    "1": ObjectId("4f4ba859c883fdf85e003af2")
   ]
},
"_id": ObjectId("4f4bb608c883fd7860000001"),
"createdat": ISODate("2012-02-27T16: 57: 44.0Z"),
```

I found it strange to have a $pushAll field but, well, I can read that with $e->getP();

However, it stops me when I try to attach a file to E :

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="P", simple="true")
 * @MongoDB\Index
 */
 protected $p = array();

/** @MongoDB\File */
private $file;
```

Because when I try to `$e->setFile($filename)` and persist/flush, I end up with that error:

```
[MongoCursorException]                  
document to insert can't have $ fields
```

Error which obviously refers to that strange `$pushAll` field.

If I manually modify my document in MongoDB with that kind of entry :

```
"p": [
  "0": ObjectId("4f4ba859c883fdf85e00313a"),
  "1": ObjectId("4f4ba859c883fdf85e003af2")
],
"_id": ObjectId("4f4bb608c883fd7860000001"),
"createdat": ISODate("2012-02-27T16: 57: 44.0Z")
```

...then everything's fine again, I can save my file without any error.

Ok, its sounds like I'm missing something or that I didn't RTFM enough on that `ReferenceMany` part, but I still came here to see if someone had a already gone into that.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You probably already figured this out. But Doctrine MongoDB ODM is having major troubles at the moment working with GridFS collections. References breaks bad.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, that was a doctrine's bug. I've finally made a dirty workaround for that...